# find the image of the real line (y = 0) and imaginary line (x = 0) f(z) = z^2+z

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

f(z) = z^2 + z
For real line I did z = x + iy

got x^2 + 2xiy + iy + x - y

made y=0 to get x^2 + x.

For the imaginary line do I just make x=0 similarly?

Comment: Yes, that's right: put $\;x=0\;$ and evaluate.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).